# BlueJ Package Does Not Exist Error

Tags: java, import, package, bluej

I'm using the jid3 library to extract information from mp3 files. I've downloaded the jar and added it to the BlueJ libraries.

My import lines are as follows

```
import org.blinkenlights.jid3.*;
import org.blinkenlights.jid3.v1.*;
import org.blinkenlights.jid3.v2.*;
```

although I'm getting

```
Package org.blinkenlights.jid3 does not exist
```

I've been googling for a while now and can't seem to find what the issue is, does anyone have any ideas? This is the same import lines used in a library example here

```
http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/samples.html
```

and as showed in the library documentation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. from the Bluej projects window, select Tools -> Preferences menu
2. select `Libraries` tab
3. click the `add` button
4. navigate to the jid3.jar file
5. make sure the jar file is added to the list of added jars
6. RESTART BLUEJ

You should be good to go.